# Subsequence to infinity proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to prove this:

> Every not bounded above sequence has a subsequence which limit is infinity when $n\to \infty$.

It's nearly the same what Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem says, but there sequence must be bounded. Any hints and proofs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that a sequence $\{x_n\}$ is not bounded above. Construct a subsequence as follows:

Let $x_{n_1} = x_1$.  Since the sequence is not bounded above, there is some $x_i$ further into the sequence such that $x_i > \max\{x_{n_1},1\}$.  Call this $x_{n_2}$.

For each $x_{n_k}$, there is some $x_i$ further into the sequence such that $x_i > \max\{x_{n_k},k\}$.  Call this $x_{n_{k+1}}$.

Proceeding indefinitely, we produce a strictly increasing subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^\infty$ of $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that is not bounded above.

Comment: you are God, sir

Comment: You will know that you have understood the material when you begin to think "well duh, why didn't I think of that?".  With enough practice, you just get the hang of it.  Glad to help.

Comment: I am practising. If I am lost I post question